# Is UIFont thread safe in iOs 4.0?

Tags: multithreading, uifont

according to the documents(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html)

**Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads. 
String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.**

Does it mean that UIFont is thread safe in iOs 4.0?

But when I use UIFont in my code, it sometimes crashes in code:[UIFont sizeWithFont:myfont];
And I just measure some text size in background thread.

If I can't use UIFont in background thread,how can I measure text size:(instead of [UIFont sizeWithFont:myfont])?

Thank you.